# Replace random elements in list with random values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, replace

I have the following set of values stored in a list.

```
[-1.7683218, 0.22206295, -0.28429198, 5.925369, -3.952484, -3.0728238, 0.09690776, -0.31914753, 3.9695702, 26.934353, 1.4882066, 1.8194668, -0.5614318, 1.2354431, -0.09714768, -0.15579335, -0.059994906, 1.0105655, -23.25607, 31.982368, -0.09390785, 0.17786688, 0.36164832, -4.673975, 13.495866, -3.57134, 0.5583399, -1.801314, 2.4207468, 2.0513844, -3.429592, -9.599998, 23.412394, -3.963623, 6.930485, 2.5186272, 0.6805691, -1.1615586, -0.915736, -2.6307302, -14.409785, 0.6327307, 10.512744, -0.09292421, -0.61977243, 0.35928893, -1.3844814, 8.098062, -0.8270248, 0.47219157, 0.089366496, 0.9056338, 1.5297629, 3.3246832, -0.9748858, 36.62332, -1.0525678, -0.87139374, 6.7600174, 36.210625, -0.25728267, 14.568578, 0.87466383, -4.2237897, -5.4309, 19.762472, 0.8426512, -0.7807278, 0.03435099, 12.787761, -4.9308186, -1.4322343, 0.49790275, -12.979129, 0.18121482, -0.81953144, -1.5393608, 17.757078, 3.5726204, -11.319154, -0.002896044, -1.8806648, 0.30027565, -2.6210017, 16.230186, -2.2566936, 37.37506, -2.7738526, -0.91440165, -3.652771, 1.8378688, -0.25519317, 0.5222581, 0.2189773, 23.825306, 0.3779062, 2.6709516, 0.84001434, -0.41394734, -0.600579, -3.1629875, 0.2880843, -3.9132822, 5.674796, -0.5569526, 0.30253112, -4.4269695, 4.5206604, -0.8477638, 0.0032483074, -2.2814171, 0.5524869, -1.4271426, -0.24263692, 1.0095457, -3.187037, -1.6656531, 1.4805393, 0.064992905, -4.8124804, -0.07194552, -0.28692132, -0.19502515, 0.010771384, -32.744797, 1.2642047, 6.3942785, -1.2971659, 29.70087, 0.19707158, -2.734262, 2.8497686, -1.710305, -1.3836008, 22.758884, -1.8488939, 4.1740856, 0.26019523, -8.814447, -3.937495, 0.22731477, -0.7874651, 17.22002, -7.89242, -0.5795766, 3.3960745, 1.0440702, 0.5483718, 1.2849183, -0.63732344, -40.38428, -4.25527, 3.034935, 0.25527972, -0.81940174, -7.0720696, 1.7420169, 14.904871, -1.5399592, 0.20110837, 0.1902977, 2.5790472, -28.560707, 0.09560776, -0.973604, 0.6214314, -5.1268454, -0.9104073, 33.082394, 0.23800176, -9.696023, 12.288443, -16.52249, -7.6811, -21.928356, 25.690449, -0.6803232, -1.4738222, -1.831514, 0.00013296002, -3.1330614, 3.6067219, -3.0617614, -6.334016, -24.856865, -6.0669985, 2.8829474, 0.76423097, -0.21836776, -2.3173273, -2.092735, -0.19577695, 4.2984896, 0.029742926, 1.0902604, -0.28707412, -0.1671038, -0.4607489, -15.966867, -1.7149612, -1.3445716, 1.400264, 4.906401, -6.314724, -0.92188597, -0.14341217, -6.819194, 1.2750683, 21.634096, 0.5503013, 5.2122655, -0.096101895, -0.69029164, 2.6239898, -26.33101, -3.7901835, 10.026649, 1.0661886, 0.8891293, 34.24628, -0.9036363, -4.4846773, -30.846636, -5.8609247, -0.018534392, 4.657759e-06, 16.96108, 10.725708, -0.3170653, -3.2331817, 0.73887914, 0.69840825, 0.9043666, 1.0727708, 1.6571997, -0.70257163, 2.4863558, 0.07501343, -35.059708, 0.72496796, -3.0723267, -3.2004805, -0.9447444, 0.56954986, 2.6018164, -0.49256825, 22.71359, 0.45523545, -2.1936522, 4.008838, 0.62327665, 10.315046, 1.4006382, 1.1290226, 1.2660133, -8.46607]
```

I want to be able to create 100 more lists that are similar to this one but contain randomly chosen different random values within the highest and lowest values of the original list. Let's consider a smaller example to better understand the problem. Let's consider that I have the list with highest lowest value -1 and highest value 7.2.

```
original list   :  [0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 2.5, 7.2, -1]
random list 1   :  [0.5, 0.2, 1.4, 4.5, 6.2, -0.5]
random list 2   :  [5.3, 0.3, 0.7, 2.3, 4.2, -0.1]
....
random list 100 :  [0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 2,1, 6.5, -1]
```

The key is that not all values have to change(in some cases they can like in list 2 for example). Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do this, and without knowing the use case it will be shooting in the dark: You could randomly pick 1 element and just randomly pick 100 numbers between min & max to build new lists with just that one element changed. That fits the prompt but probably doesn't generate the randomness you're looking for... can you [edit] your question to clarify what the intent is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code prints what you need as the output. First you have to find the max and min numbers in the original list and then you have to use random library and random.uniform() function to get what you need.

```
import random
original_list = [0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 2.5, 7.2, -1]
max_number = max(original_list)
min_number = min(original_list)

'''because you need 100 more lists'''
for i in range(100):
    random_list = []
    for j in range(len(original_list)):
        random_list.append(round(random.uniform(min_number,max_number),1))
    print('random list '+str(i+1)+' ', end='')
    print(random_list)
```

Comment: It's worth noting this does *not* guarantee uniqueness of the generated lists. The example list has ~377M possible outcomes rounded to tenths, but there is a chance of collision.

Answer (score 1):

```
smallest = min(original_list)
largest = max(original_list)

newlist1 = [random.uniform(smallest, largest) for _ in range(len(original_list))]
newlist2 = [random.uniform(smallest, largest) for _ in range(len(original_list))]
# and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
import numpy as np

orig = [-1.7683218, 0.22206295, -0.28429198, 5.925369, -3.952484, -3.0728238, 0.09690776, -0.31914753, 3.9695702, 26.934353, 1.4882066, 1.8194668, -0.5614318, 1.2354431, -0.09714768, -0.15579335, -0.059994906, 1.0105655, -23.25607, 31.982368, -0.09390785, 0.17786688, 0.36164832, -4.673975, 13.495866, -3.57134, 0.5583399, -1.801314, 2.4207468, 2.0513844, -3.429592, -9.599998, 23.412394, -3.963623, 6.930485, 2.5186272, 0.6805691, -1.1615586, -0.915736, -2.6307302, -14.409785, 0.6327307, 10.512744, -0.09292421, -0.61977243, 0.35928893, -1.3844814, 8.098062, -0.8270248, 0.47219157, 0.089366496, 0.9056338, 1.5297629, 3.3246832, -0.9748858, 36.62332, -1.0525678, -0.87139374, 6.7600174, 36.210625, -0.25728267, 14.568578, 0.87466383, -4.2237897, -5.4309, 19.762472, 0.8426512, -0.7807278, 0.03435099, 12.787761, -4.9308186, -1.4322343, 0.49790275, -12.979129, 0.18121482, -0.81953144, -1.5393608, 17.757078, 3.5726204, -11.319154, -0.002896044, -1.8806648, 0.30027565, -2.6210017, 16.230186, -2.2566936, 37.37506, -2.7738526, -0.91440165, -3.652771, 1.8378688, -0.25519317, 0.5222581, 0.2189773, 23.825306, 0.3779062, 2.6709516, 0.84001434, -0.41394734, -0.600579, -3.1629875, 0.2880843, -3.9132822, 5.674796, -0.5569526, 0.30253112, -4.4269695, 4.5206604, -0.8477638, 0.0032483074, -2.2814171, 0.5524869, -1.4271426, -0.24263692, 1.0095457, -3.187037, -1.6656531, 1.4805393, 0.064992905, -4.8124804, -0.07194552, -0.28692132, -0.19502515, 0.010771384, -32.744797, 1.2642047, 6.3942785, -1.2971659, 29.70087, 0.19707158, -2.734262, 2.8497686, -1.710305, -1.3836008, 22.758884, -1.8488939, 4.1740856, 0.26019523, -8.814447, -3.937495, 0.22731477, -0.7874651, 17.22002, -7.89242, -0.5795766, 3.3960745, 1.0440702, 0.5483718, 1.2849183, -0.63732344, -40.38428, -4.25527, 3.034935, 0.25527972, -0.81940174, -7.0720696, 1.7420169, 14.904871, -1.5399592, 0.20110837, 0.1902977, 2.5790472, -28.560707, 0.09560776, -0.973604, 0.6214314, -5.1268454, -0.9104073, 33.082394, 0.23800176, -9.696023, 12.288443, -16.52249, -7.6811, -21.928356, 25.690449, -0.6803232, -1.4738222, -1.831514, 0.00013296002, -3.1330614, 3.6067219, -3.0617614, -6.334016, -24.856865, -6.0669985, 2.8829474, 0.76423097, -0.21836776, -2.3173273, -2.092735, -0.19577695, 4.2984896, 0.029742926, 1.0902604, -0.28707412, -0.1671038, -0.4607489, -15.966867, -1.7149612, -1.3445716, 1.400264, 4.906401, -6.314724, -0.92188597, -0.14341217, -6.819194, 1.2750683, 21.634096, 0.5503013, 5.2122655, -0.096101895, -0.69029164, 2.6239898, -26.33101, -3.7901835, 10.026649, 1.0661886, 0.8891293, 34.24628, -0.9036363, -4.4846773, -30.846636, -5.8609247, -0.018534392, 4.657759e-06, 16.96108, 10.725708, -0.3170653, -3.2331817, 0.73887914, 0.69840825, 0.9043666, 1.0727708, 1.6571997, -0.70257163, 2.4863558, 0.07501343, -35.059708, 0.72496796, -3.0723267, -3.2004805, -0.9447444, 0.56954986, 2.6018164, -0.49256825, 22.71359, 0.45523545, -2.1936522, 4.008838, 0.62327665, 10.315046, 1.4006382, 1.1290226, 1.2660133, -8.46607]

a = min(orig)
b = max(orig)
n = len(orig)
res = [[np.random.uniform(a,b,n)] for i in range(100)]
```

and you get `res` which is a list of `100` lists (with size `len(orig)`) of uniformly distributed numbers over `[min(orig), max(orig))`.